# How do I reference a JSON parameter in a Mule JDBC query?

Tags: mule

I'm Passing JSON data to Mule, if I echo the Payload I get this:

```
{"AddJob":{"JobNumber":12345,"Version":1}}
```

I want to insert those values into a table using a JDBC query.  What do I replace "????" with below to reference those JSON parameters?  Do I need to convert it to an Object first?

```
<jdbc:query key="insertQuery" value="INSERT INTO [dbo].[Jobs] ([[JOB_NUMBER], [VERSION]) VALUES (???? , ????)"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With MEL introduced in 3.3.0, the recommended approach is to transform the JSON payload to Map:

```
<json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="java.util.HashMap"/>
```

then use MEL expressions in the query:

```
<jdbc:query key="insertQuery"
            value="INSERT INTO [dbo].[Jobs] ([[JOB_NUMBER], [VERSION]) VALUES (#[message.payload.AddJob.JobNumber], #[message.payload.AddJob.Version])"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

For this use case you should consider using the [Json expression evaluator](http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/module/json/JsonExpressionEvaluator.html) provided by mule.

Your jdbc query would look like the following

```
<jdbc:query key="insertQuery" value="INSERT INTO [dbo].[Jobs] ([[JOB_NUMBER], [VERSION]) VALUES (#[json: AddJob/JobNumber] , #[json: AddJob/Version])"/>
```

Comment: To future-proof the config, on Mule 3.3.0 and above it's better to not use the individual evaluators, like `json`, but instead use MEL. Individual evaluators may be removed in a future major release.

Comment: Thanks, I initially did it this way (which worked) then switched to the MEL expressions.

Comment: The reason why I've suggested you this approach was because i didn't know what version of mule you were using. If using mule 3.3.0 MEL is definitively the way to go.